# Recommend a diff tool to show and explain some changes in a document

Tags: documents, diff, comments

Now I'm in process of contract negotiation with a private company. They sending me the contract, I'm making some changes and then sending back to them for verification. Now they asking me to explain every change I done, but I can't remember them all. MSWord's diff tool is displaying too many useless changes, and I can't "ignore" some of them manually.

I guess I need something similar to [KDiff](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/) tool, but with these extra features:

- the ability to comment some
  differences between 2 versions of a
  text file.
- the ability to ignore some
  non-significant differences (for
  example, changing hyphen into dash,
  or removing multiple spaces)
- the ability to create an HTML or PDF
  report with explanations about
  changes.

Can you recommend some tool for my task? (freeware is preferred)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SmartBear CodeCollaborator](http://smartbear.com/products/development-tools/code-review/) does that stuff, but it's not free.  However, they've occasionally offered specials for a limited 5-user version of CodeReviewer for as little as $5.